# Analyzing statement and finding probability from given PDF.

Tags: probability

A batch of small calibre ammunition is accepted as satisfactory if none of a sample of five shots falls more than $2$ feet from the centre of the target at a given range. If X, the distance from the centre of the target to a given impact point has density $f(x)=k2xe^{-x^2}$ for $0<x<3$. What is the value of $k$ and what is the probability that the batch will be accepted?

**My input**

Finding $k$

We know $\int_{0}^{3}f(x)=1$

$k\int_{0}^{3}2xe^{-x^2}\implies k
\cdot1-e^{-9}=1$

$k=\dfrac{1}{1-e^{-9}} $

$P(X<2)=P(\text{Single shot falling between zero to 2 feet(acceptable range))}=k\int_{0}^{2}2xe^{-x^2}=k\cdot(1-e^{-4})=\dfrac
{1-e^{-4}}{1-e^{-9}}$

Let $\dfrac
{1-e^{-4}}{1-e^{-9}}=U$

Required probability using Binomial theorem is $= U^5$

Can anyone help me and tell if I did everything right? I am having a strange feeling that probability I calculated is wrong. I never encountered any of my probabilities in terms of $e$. Please, someome check it.Any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone help me and tell if I did everything right?

Your approach is correct. However, you can improve on the notation.

- First of all, I never saw a formula with a number in between two variables, so I would write $f(x)=2kxe^{-x^2}$.
- Secondly, you forget to mention which variable you use to integrate, so $\int_0^3 f(x)$ should be $\int_0^3 f(x) \, \text{d}x$ and $\int_0^3 2xe^{-x^2}$ should be $\int_0^3 2xe^{-x^2} \, \text{d}x$.
- Thirdly, you forget the parentheses when computing $k$, so $k\cdot 1 - e^{-9}$ should be $k \cdot (1-e^{-9})$.

> Any other way to solve this problem?

To me, it seems that your approach is the most straightforward approach.

Comment: Nice man! Got to know some mistakes thanks.